Best way to deploy a worker service with Hangfire in Azure?
So I am developing a worker service with Hangfire. It will have some recurring jobs which will e scheduled and managed by Hangfire. All of this is working great.
Now, I want to deploy it in Azure and confused between Azure app service and web jobs.
I have done several research and did not found a good resource on how to deploy a worker service with hangfire in Azure. Microsoft has some documentation but that mainly concerns the web jobs.
I have several questions,

Which is recomended for worker service with Hangfire? Azure app service or web jobs?
If I deploy it in app service, How will I do that?
If I deploy it in web job, How will I do that?
In case of App service, is there any chance that the app service will be off in case there is no job running for some time?
Is there any documentation or article that discuss this things in details?


"Is there any documentation or article that discuss this things in details?" - Google?

From memory - I think you'd need a copy of your app, as Hangfire just runs the same code under the hood - same libs, same models etc.
I could be wrong, and maybe you need only a small app with access to the libraries.
PLENTY of documentation here..
https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-in-background.html
Why don't you create a sample app and experiment?
As for deploying - there are many ways - CICD? Manual?
Will the app be off? No - not unless you set 'Always On' to false - in which case it may go to sleep (but you'll still be paying for it)
